# Why does MC / Visa Exclude Jamaica from rental car insurance

Tags: car-rentals, insurance

Why is it that MC / Visa exclude auto-rental liability that is found in most other countries?  I ask because:

1. If there is something 'special' about Jamaica, I'd like to know
2. It's $30 a day to buy limited liability from the vendor

The cost of buying from the vendor almost doubles the price.  What is 'driving' these outcomes?  Any clever suggestions / lessons learned are appreciated.

Comment: When an insurance company excludes something, or charges high prices, it is usually because they have a high rate of expensive claims.

Comment: Seeing as how Visa excludes Jamaica, Israel and both Irelands, one might guess it is due to laws within those countries regarding providing 3rd party coverage, as there are plenty of countries in the world with far worse theft - accident rates than the four Visa excluded.

Comment: Probably because of high rates of insurance fraud.

Comment: @Tom: Chase Sapphire seem to offer CDW in all those countries. Mastercard World used to offer it too (maybe still does). So I doubt it is law-related.

Comment: @GeorgeY.  The insurance coverage pamphlet that came with my Chase card has the follow caveat on CDW coverage: _The benefit is available in the United States and most foreign countries. **Coverage is not available where it is prohibited by law** or by individual merchants, or is in violation of the territory terms of the rental agreement._

Comment: @Tom but before those locations were explicitly excluded in Chase Sapphire. Now (I believe since 2013) they are not excluded. And I know people who used it to get coverage in Israel.

Comment: @GeorgeY. - their current verbiage is more generic allowing leeways for countries and rules to change.  Visa's and Chase's old version were more locked down.

Comment: Yes, it helps them to avoid the situation when the law in country X changes tomorrow. But it is not a meaningless change, or everyone in the US would follow the suit and not look like losing some competition.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can only speculate why a company would behave as it does, and knowing the answer to the question doesn't affect any travel decisions the asker might make.

Comment: @DavidRicherby:  The conversation affects the decision of whether to rent a car or to seek other transport modalities.  The fact of the matter is that Jamaica drivers and road conditions are exceptionally dangerous: one of the reason why insurance is expensive and most likely a reason for credit cards are not covering insurance.  Unless you are exceptionally safe operator (i.e. can fly a plane) and have significant experience driving on the left, driving is best left to others.  By inferring from policy / practice: one can make better decisions

Comment: @gatorback Then clarify your question. Are you actually asking if it is dangerous to drive in Jamaica? If so, your question should be about that, but bear in mind that it's likely to be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: Yes, I had considered this, however, I would expect it to be summarily closed by the question police.  Unfortunately, experience is shunned in these forums as opinion.   Risk (danger) is only one factor that drives the decision to rent or hire.  The question is posed as it was because I sought to understand the perspective of insurance so I can form my own opinion of driving risk in that frontier.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Mastercard Guide to Benefits](https://www.mastercard.com/us/personal/en/cardholderservices/guidetobenefits/pdf/11660_rent_save_EXDwar_2006.pdf):

> In general, coverage applies worldwide, but there are exceptions:
>
> - Coverage is not available for vehicles rented in the following countries: Ireland, Israel, or Jamaica.
> - You may be unable to receive benefits in Australia, Italy, or New Zealand. Please contact your
>     vehicle rental agency before you travel.
> - **Coverage is not available where prohibited by law.**

Therefore the likely answer is that Jamaica doesn't allow Mastercard to provide their insurance services there.